# Why do we create empty static Command classes in Contracts of r3 Corda? What is the significance of them being empty ? What is their use?

Tags: corda

I know we use Commands to use different Contract code for different types of transactions but I was not able to understand why they are empty and how they are used.

I am a beginner in learning R3 Corda. So, please forgive if my doubt is naive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Commands are used to identify the intent of the transaction so that the correct contract logic can be validated in the contract.

The command is an empty class for a simple use case but for some complex use case the command class may be used to accompany additional command data. The command data could be any random information that might be needed as part of the transaction (frequently contract validation) but is not available in the input/ output of the transaction. Hence it's designed to be a class.

A simple case when you might need command to carry additional data is when you use an oracle in the network like in this example below:

https://github.com/corda/samples/blob/release-V4/oracle-example/base-java/src/main/java/net/corda/examples/oracle/base/contract/PrimeContract.java

Hope this help!